# How to assign webcontent path to load resources

Tags: html, eclipse

I am getting 404 error while load css in my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>-------------</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/css/hompage.css">
</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

every time I am confusing and not able to load resources. 
How to target resource of eclipse to load in browser. I have doubt **href="../../resources/css/hompage.css** path only plese find attachement. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try move your css file, or if IDE support it, use absolute path, like /css/***